# How do I set a property of the feature control loaded within a delegate control?

Tags: 2007, delegate, properties

I'm currently have a delegate control as such;

```
<SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="MainNavigation" AllowMultipleControls="true">
```

I also have a feature which has a element manifest file containing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <Control Id="MainNavigation" Sequence="100" ControlSrc="~/_controltemplates/MainNavigation.ascx">
        <Property Name="Theme"></Property>
    </Control>
</Elements>
```

Whenever I try to update the delegatecontrol to set the "Theme" property an error is raised. I tried using:

```
<SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="MainNavigation" AllowMultipleControls="true">
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I havent used properties in delegates in a long time, but dont you need to set the value in your control?

```
<Property Name="Theme">MyValue</Property>
```

Comment: Hi Anders, I also tried this but the control property was not set when testing.